# Weird MapView problem; PixelConverter Error

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview

I have an application based on the MapActivity.  The application drops
ItemizedOverlay items on the map as you start to move about.  It has
been running with no problems until I dropped it into a Nexus 2.2
phone.

I'm running into a weird problem where sometimes when I zoom in/out
too fast, or pan too fast, the MapView will go "white" and my Overlay
items will get shoved into the upper left hand corner.

The only error I've seen in my log is:

E/PixelConverter( 4881): Setting singular matrix Matrix{[0.0, 0.0,
152.0][0.0, 0.0, 347.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

My Map keys are working fine.  I have internet permissions setup on
the phone too.

I'm scratching my head over this one.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Has anyone found a workaround yet?

Comment: restarting the phone like in ol' Win days helps me all the time I face this issue

Answer (score 5):

Issue has been reported. Go to the page below and press the star to raise some attention to this problem.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13172