# MapView MultiTouch zoom (Pinching) unreliable and chaotic

Tags: android, android-mapview, multi-touch

I use the MapView from Google and have real bigger problem with it. Especially with the multitouch zooming. I am using an Android 2.2 Tablet. First thing needed to make this working was specifing in the AndroidManifest that xlarge screens are supported.

So what happen now. 90 % of the time zooming works. But sometimes it does not work and all my **overlays** (I also use Views from mapballons project to display on top of the map) are **moving around** while the **tiles stay at the same position**. Zooming does not work anymore. After some seconds and touching around as dump it begins to work again.

I don't know why that happens, and there are no exception in the logcat.

I have also attached an SimpleGestureListener on the MapView but don't consume gestures which are important (only Double Tap). But the problem also occurs without a GestureListener.

It would be helpful if someone had also such strange behaviour and know why that happens.

EDIT: While in that strange mode, it is also not possible to zoom with the zoom button and toggle to satelite. It totally reacts strange

EDIT2: I can confirm this is in more application i have on the 2.2 Tablet. It also occurs mainly when you start pinnching in the left side of the map

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the same problem posted here: [Weird MapView problem; PixelConverter Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3815551/543136)

Comment: It could be the problem, but i got no logcat outputs and no white banner what they mention. Also it occurs mainly on the left side of the MapView

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it happens on the left side of the MapView is because your thumb is registered as a multi-touch. Some caculation gets fudged up when that happens.