# Alternative Pinch-to-Zoom for MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, multi-touch

Is there any way to implement a alternative Pinch-To-Zoom for the MapView? Because i have problems with original zoom -> [MapView MultiTouch zoom (Pinching) unreliable and chaotic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993832/mapview-multitouch-zoom-pinching-unreliable-and-chaotic), it would be great to implement that by own. For example with the multi-touch-controller project. Or is there too much going on internally in the MapView to build a good zooming? (I think about the sizing while you are in zoom gesture, can't imagine how to do this)

Answer (score 0):

You can always intercept touch events in an overlay, and calculate your own zoom.

Comment: Yes this won't be the problem. The problem i see is that this won't be fluid because you scroll in steps, like you would push on a button. The Pinch-To-Zoom looks like it draws some steps more beetween 2 zoom levels